# Is relevant the order of INSERTion in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

I have multiple tables, related by multiple foreign keys as in the following example:

- `Chefs(id_chef,name,stars)` - where `id_chef` is the primary key.
- `Recipes(id_recipe,name,calories,category)` - `id_recipe` as PK.
- `Ingredients(id_ing,name,type)` - `id_ing` as PK.
- `Contains(id_chef,id_recipe,quantity,unit)` - `(id_chef,id_recipe)` as PK, and as Foreign Keys for `Recipes(id_recipe)` and `Chefs(id_chef)`.
- `Autorship(id_chef,id_recipe)` - Same as previous.
- `Users(user_id,name)` - `user_id` as PK.
- `Evaluation(user_id,id_recipe,stars)` - `(user_id,id_recipe)` as PK and Foreign Keys for `User(user_id)` and `Recipes(id_recipe)`.

The question is, now that I want to INSERT some data in all these tables with one only script, do I have to do it in a specific order and respect some condition, or is it indifferent?

Thanks.

Comment: No, as long as the Foreign Keys you reference exist

Comment: So the order is only important when I create them, right? I mean, I can't reference `Users(user_id)` if I haven't created `Users` yet, am I right? Doesn't affect the insertion?

Comment: you cant reference `user_id` if you did not create that user ID yet, e.g. `Users` contain Users 1,2,3,4 you wont be able to insert into `Evaluation` using `user_id` `5`

Comment: The order is only relevant if you have specified a foreign key constraint on an innodb table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexander, you're correct that you can't reference what doesn't exist yet.  But your script will need some planning when you run it, so order of insertion will matter somewhat.  You want to make sure that all referenced tables (Primary keys) are loaded before their referencing keys are loaded.

When I'm planning my load scripts, I arrange my tables so that the most referenced are loaded first and then all others load after that.

I note for example that the 'Chefs' table is referenced twice.  You'll want to load that table before you load the 'Contains' and the 'Autorship' tables.  The same applies for the 'Recipes' table.

I would probably tool my script to load Chefs, Autorship, and Users first, and then load the rest.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Foreign key checks can also be disabled at the start of a script, and re-enabled at the end of it. But I do not believe the constraints are re-checked when enabled, so make sure the data inserted then is well formed.